# How to be able to apply some operation to dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, dictionary

Imagine I have a dictionary with elements being lists. Something like

```
{ label1:[ el1 ,el2,el3], label2:[el4,el5]}
```

And I have this in a variable object. My goal is to reach the elements el1, el2, etc and apply some operation to them.

I can do that by

```
if isinstance(object,dict):
   for k,v in object.items():
       print(v) #<--this is the list
       for el in v:
          apply_op(el)
```

This is all fine and dandy but what if I want this algorithm to be applicable for different levels. So for example instead of the dict above I have

```
{ particle: { label1:[ el1 ,el2,el3], label2:[el4,el5]}}
```

As you can see this is one level deeper.

I would like to have an algorithm that still finds the elements and applies the operation, no matter how deep or shallow these elements are. How can I do that , without just writing a special case for every level?

Comment: are you looking for recursion?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use recursion here, Something like this.

```
def fun(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        res = ""
        for key, val in d.items():
            res += fun(val)
        return res
    else:
        return "-".join(d)
```

joining can be replaced with the operation you want to do.

```
d = {'label1': ['el1', 'el2', 'el3'], 'label2': ['el4', 'el5']}
x = {'particle': {'label1': ['el1', 'el2', 'el3'], 'label2': ['el4', 'el5']}}
y = y = {"something": {'particle': {'label1': ['el1', 'el2', 'el3'], 'label2': ['el4', 'el5']}, "more": {"nums": ["num1", "num2"]}}}

fun(d) # el1-el2-el3el4-el5
fun(x) # el1-el2-el3el4-el5
fun(y) # el1-el2-el3el4-el5num1-num2
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, seems like recursion would be a good strategy:

```
def apply(foo, d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            apply(foo, v)
        else:
            foo(v)
```

So whenever a `dict` is found, there is a new call to `apply`, regardless of the depth.  As an example:

```
def append999(l):
    l.append(999)

d = {'adict': {'1':[1], '2':[2], 'bdict':{3:[3]}}}

apply(append999, d)
print(d)
```

Result:

```
{'adict': {'1': [1, 999], '2': [2, 999], 'bdict': {3: [3, 999]}}}
```

If the internal list was containing mutable objects (like not `int`), then you could have a loop over all the elements of the list which was altering the elements.  Here is such an example, where `apply` is also modified to allow `*args` and `**kwargs` to be passed to the applied function:

```
def apply(foo, d, *args, **kwargs):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            apply(foo, v, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # now we are looping over the assumed lists
            for i in v:
                # and applying with extra arguments
                foo(i, *args, **kwargs)

# here is a basic mutable object
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Bar({self.x})"

# here is a function to increase our mutable object
def increase(bar, amount):
    bar.x += amount

d = {'adict': {'1':[Bar(1)], '2':[Bar(2)], 'bdict':{3:[Bar(3)]}}}
apply(increase, d, amount=10)
print(d)
```

Result:

```
{'adict': {'1': [Bar(11)], '2': [Bar(12)], 'bdict': {3: [Bar(13)]}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use recursion here. Assuming that you want to apply some processing to anything that is a *scalar* value (including unicode and byte strings) at whatever depth in mappings and lists or any other iterable, you could write:

```
import collections.abc

def deep_process(obj):
    # scalars, including unicode and byte strings
    if isinstance(obj, (str, bytes))or not isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Iterable):
        apply_op(obj)
    # mappings
    elif isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Mapping):
        for v in obj.values():
            deep_process(v)
    # other iterables like lists or tuples
    else:
        for v in obj:
            deep_process(v)
```

Demo (with `apply_op = print`)

```
deep_process({'particle': {'label1': ['el1', 'el2', 'el3'], 'label2': ['el4', 'el5']}})

el1
el2
el3
el4
el5
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting tool called [lenses](https://pypi.org/project/lenses/) for traversing and manipulating nested data structures.

```py
from lenses import lens

def apply_op(n):
    return n + 1

# create a lens object that will find all lists recursively
find_lists = lens.Recur(list)

data = {'particle': {'label1': [1, 2, 3], 'label2': [4, 5]}}

# apply the operation to each item of all lists
new_data = find_lists.Each().modify(apply_op)(data)
```

Result:

```
>>> new_data
{'particle': {'label1': [2, 3, 4], 'label2': [5, 6]}}
```

The original `data` remains intact after this operation:

```
>>> data
{'particle': {'label1': [1, 2, 3], 'label2': [4, 5]}}
```

If you want to modify `data` in-place, you have to access the individual lists using the `collect` method and mutate them by yourself:

```py
for list_ in find_lists.collect()(data):
    for i, item in enumerate(list_):
        list_[i] = apply_op(item)
```

Result:

```
>>> data
{'particle': {'label1': [2, 3, 4], 'label2': [5, 6]}}
```